# How to change the mouse radius size with mouse hold down and drag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The goal is when holding down the mouse left button and dragging the mouse that it will create a circle around the mouse first time click down position and then when dragging the mouse around it will resize up the circle radius on xRadius and yRadius.

For testing it I set the xRadius and yRadius to 0 at the Start()

I also added helper bool flag

```
private bool isMouseDown = false;
```

Then in Update added OnMouseDown and OnMouseDrag events

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, xRadius, targetLayers))
        {
            Debug.Log("player detected");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("player NOT detected");
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        xRadius = xRadius + 0.01f;
        yRadius = yRadius + 0.01f;
        CreatePoints();
    }
```

but when I just hold the mouse down without any dragging yet it's changing the circle radius size.
it seems that OnMouseDrag is working like when holding the mouse down even without dragging it at all.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnityEngine.LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(1, 50)] public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float xRadius = 5;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float yRadius = 5;
    [Range(0.1f, 5)] public float width = 0.1f;
    [Range(0, 100)] public float height = 0;
    public bool controlBothXradiusYradius = false;
    public bool draw = true;

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask targetLayers;
    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;

    private bool isMouseDown = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        xRadius = 0;
        yRadius = 0;

        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if (draw)
            CreatePoints();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, xRadius, targetLayers))
        {
            Debug.Log("player detected");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("player NOT detected");
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        xRadius = xRadius + 0.01f;
        yRadius = yRadius + 0.01f;
        CreatePoints();
    }

    public void CreatePoints()
    {
        line.enabled = true;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;

        float x;
        float y;

        var angle = 20f;
        var points = new Vector3[segments + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < segments + 1; i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xRadius;
            y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yRadius;

            points[i] = new Vector3(x, height, y);

            angle += (360f / segments);
        }
       
        line.SetPositions(points);
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private float prevXRadius, prevYRadius;
    private int prevSegments;
    private float prevWidth;
    private float prevHeight;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (!line) return;

        if (!draw)
        {
            line.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            line.enabled = true;

            if (xRadius != prevXRadius || yRadius != prevYRadius || segments != prevSegments || width != prevWidth || height != prevHeight)
            {
                CreatePoints();

                prevXRadius = xRadius;
                prevYRadius = yRadius;
                prevSegments = segments;
                prevWidth = width;
                prevHeight = height;
            }

            if (controlBothXradiusYradius)
            {
                yRadius = xRadius;
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing all these on the interactive objects why not rather go the other way round and have one single script on the player itself and from there either check via `Physics.CheckSphere` if you are close to an interactive object or use a `Physics.SphereCast` with the mouse and desired radius and check if you hit an interactive object that way?

Comment: Also why for the drag/radius you don't rather use the actual mouse delta position instead of a hardcoded `0.01` ?

Comment: @derHugo I will explain a bit more.  The logic is like in strategy games when you select for example npc and it's making a circle around the npc and then you can make some actions with the selected npc.  In my logic when you select the object/npc/player and make a circle around it the circle will be the limited distance object can move inside the circle radius to the edge of the circle.  Also make it dynamic in runtime for example npc is moving to some position and then I draw around him a circle so the npc will not be able to keep moving out of the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Shingo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70904187/7111561) said you have to take the mouse position into account!

However, in order to actually make this work I would make some additions.

Have in mind: The mouse position is in **pixel space**! So you will want to somehow convert it to world space coordinates.

I would do something like this

```
// The maximum distance in world units
[SerializeField] private float maxDistance = 1f;

private Vector3 initialMousePosition;

private Plane dragPlane;

[SerializeField] private Camera _mainCamera;
private Collider _collider;

private void Awake ()
{
    _collider = GetComponent<Collider>();
    if(!_mainCamera) _mainCamera = Camera.main;
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    // Get the exact position where the mouse hits our collider
    // and also the ray direction, we will use it to get the current view plane
    // in order to map later mouse positions to the same range
    var ray = _mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    // this should usually always be true since otherwise this OnMouseDown would not have been called
    if(_collider.Raycast(ray, out var hit, float.maxValue))
    {
        initialMousePosition = hit.point;
        // Create a plane at the position of the object in XZ direction
        dragPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
    }
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    // Similar as before but this time we use the Plane as target 
    var ray = _mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if(dragPlane.Raycast(ray, out var rayDistance))
    {
        var currentMousePosition = ray.GetPoint(rayDistance);

        var distance = currentMousePosition - initialMousePosition;

        // Just to be sure erase any difference on Y 
        // (there shouldn't be any anyway since the plane is XZ only)
        distance.y = 0;
        // make sure the radius is combined maximum the maxDistance
        distance = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(distance, maxDistance);

        xRadius = distance.x;
        yRadius = distance.z;
        CreatePoints();
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on the phone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Answer (score 0):

> [OnMouseDrag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDrag.html) is called every frame while the mouse is down.

You need to check the mouse position in OnMouseDrag.

```
Vector3 mousePos;

void OnMouseDown()
{
    mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    var newMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    var delta = newMousePos - mousePos;
    if (delta.sqrMagnitude < 1)
        return;

    mousePos = newMousePos;

    xRadius = xRadius + 0.01f;
    yRadius = yRadius + 0.01f;
    CreatePoints();
}
```